# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for Java Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, arrayindexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to convert my code to lambda version and I get **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18** exception when I am building the code.

This is the working code:

```
    private void run(){
        Producer<String, String> producer = (Producer<String, String>) new KafkaProducer();
        producer.send(null, new Callback() {
            public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {  }
        });
    }
```

This code gives the error:

```
    private void run(){
        Producer<String, String> producer = (Producer<String, String>) new KafkaProducer();
        producer.send(null, (metadata,e) -> { });
    }
```

This is the Error message:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18
at aQute.lib.osgi.Clazz.parseClassFile(Clazz.java:412)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Clazz.parseClassFile(Clazz.java:333)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Clazz.parseClassFileWithCollector(Clazz.java:323)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Clazz.parseClassFile(Clazz.java:313)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Analyzer.analyzeJar(Analyzer.java:1646)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Analyzer.analyzeBundleClasspath(Analyzer.java:1534)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:115)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Builder.analyze(Builder.java:296)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Analyzer.calcManifest(Analyzer.java:292)
at aQute.lib.osgi.Builder.build(Builder.java:68)
at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.buildOSGiBundle(BundlePlugin.java:375)
at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:270)
at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:224)
at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:215)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] Error building bundle com.wso2telco:logging-extension:bundle:3.0.0 : Exception: 18
[ERROR] Error building bundle com.wso2telco:logging-extension:bundle:3.0.0 : Invalid class file: MessageSender$KafkaDataPublisher.class
[ERROR] Error(s) found in bundle configuration
```

Please note that for simplifications most of the code is removed.

Full code after simplification:(This is working code)

```
public class MessageSender {

    ExecutorService executorService = null;

    public MessageSender(ExecutorService executorService) {
       this.executorService = executorService;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String transactionLog) {
       Runnable worker = new KafkaDataPublisher();
       executorService.execute(worker);
    }

    public static class KafkaDataPublisher implements Runnable {  
       @Override
       public void run() {
          Producer<String, String> producer = (Producer<String, String>) new KafkaProducer();
          producer.send(null, new Callback() {
              public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {}
        });
       }
    }
```

}

Versions:

> Java 8

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this:

```
private void run(){
    Producer<String, String> producer = (Producer<String, String>) new KafkaProducer();
    producer.send(null, (RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) -> { });
}
```

Comment: What about like this: producer.send(null).onCompletion( (RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) -> { } );

Comment: Thanks Carlos for the help, I am unable to find a method similar to onCompletion